# ARM Assembly storing registers to memory

Tags: assembly, arm

I have the following simple program that performs an operation on two vectors; A and B (which are stored in memory) and saves the result back into memory pointed to by vector C:

```
        AREA MyProgram, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY

Start   ADR R0, VecA
        ADR R1, VecB
        ADR R2, VecC

        ; R6 is a counter
        MOV R6, #1

Loop    ; Get the value R0 is pointing to
        LDR R3, [R0], #4

        ; Get the value R1 is pointing to
        LDR R4, [R1], #4

        ; Add the values
        ADD R5, R4, R3

        ; Divide the value by 2 (i.e. shift right by 1)
        LSR R5, #1

        ; Store the resut to memory for C
        STR R5, [R2]

        ; Increment R2 to point to the next memory location
        ADD R2, R2, #4

        ; Increment the counter. If it's 9, we're done
        ; (since the vector has 8 elements)
        ADD R6, R6, #1

        CMP R6, #9
        BNE Loop
        B Done

Done    b Done ; Loop forever


        AREA MyProgram, DATA, READWRITE

VecA    DCD 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9
VecB    DCD 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9
VecC    DCD 0x0


        END
```

Eveything works fine up until the `STR R5, [R2]` instruction. The instruction doesn't seem to update the memory (the address pointed to by `R2` remains unchanged; that is, it's `0x00`). I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now and absolutely have no idea what's going wrong. The data section explicitly says `READWRITE`, so I don't understand why the memory doesn't get updated. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this code running from RAM or from FLASH?  A simple `STR` wouldn't change FLASH. I'm not sure if armasm is happy having two areas with the same name and different attributes; and I think you are missing some elements form `VecC`; and you could use `STR R5, [R2], #4`

Comment: no idea however may be you should define VecC as nice 0s instead of just a single one?

Comment: @auselen Tried that already. Didn' work.

Comment: @scott I'm running it on KEIL, so it is running from RAM. Also if I change the two section names it doesn't even compile... Moving to the next word doesn't help either.

Comment: Are you sure the simulator is simulating RAM where the code is?  If you change the area name then you'll need to change `ADR rN, VecX` to `LDR rN, =VecX` because the offset won't be known until link time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. I'm using Keil simulator and apparently I had to manually map the memory segments that I'd be writing to. I did this by clicking the `Debug -> Memory Map...` menu while the program was running and then I mapped a segment range and gave it `Read, Write, Execute` privileges.

[image]