# how can i use store registers in memory in CODE section that is ReadOnly (ARM Assembly)?

Tags: assembly, arm, keil, armasm

here's my code :

```
AREA Swap, CODE

ENTRY
    EXPORT __main

__main

ADR R0, VAR_1
ADR R1, VAR_2
LDR R2, [R0]
LDR R3, [R1]

STR R2, [R1]
STR R3, [R0]

stop    B   stop

AREA Swap, DATA, READWRITE

VAR_1 DCD 8
VAR_2 DCD 7

END
```

i can load values from addresses (r0 and r1) but i cant store them.
i know that CODE section is read only but if I add READWRITE keyword the code doesn't work properly.when i run debugger the only thing that is execute is 
MOV r0, r0 
[image]

I tried to change memory map permissions like the answer in this question :
[ARM Assembly storing registers to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317799/arm-assembly-storing-registers-to-memory)
but it doesn't work

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly, don't post images of *text*.

Comment: As for your problem, I don't know anything about the assembler you're using, but with the (uncopyable!) `AREA` directive above the data, it seems to be putting the data in the `DATA` section? When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), besides copy-pasting it as text please do it of the *failing* program.

Comment: Why are you using the same name for all your areas? From the documentation: _"All areas with the same name are placed in the same ELF section. Only the attributes of the first AREA directive of a particular name are applied."_

Comment: And depending on what version of the assembler you are using, reusing the same name may be [forbidden altogether](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Cacbjgcc.html): "You must use a different name for each area within the same source file."

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified your target processor, but it sounds like the CODE space is in Flash memory. As a general rule, the program Flash memory really is read-only at run time. At best you would go through a very specific and careful procedure to modify part of the Flash. You can't change the physical nature of the memory just by declaring it to be READWRITE for the linker.